# How to test a react dropdown form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am new to testing react components and I am struggling with increasing coverage on one of my components. Currently I have the very basic of tests that just ensure rendering and matching the snapshot but to increase coverage I would like to add a click event that changes the dropdown form option to another option in the form. [I want to click foo and have the dropdown open and i can click bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGWn.png).

```
describe("DropdownForm", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<DropdownForm choices={choices} label={label} />);
    });
    it("should match snapshot", () => {
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it("should list the number of dropdown options", () => {
        expect(wrapper.find("option").length).toEqual(3);
    });
    it("should click on the dropdown menu", async () => {
        const dropdownForm = getByText("foo");
        fireEvent.click(dropdownForm);
        const option = await waitForElement(() => getBytext("bar"), {
            wrapper
        });
        fireEvent.click(option);
        expect(handleOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Here is a snippet and obviously the last test isnt working, says foo cant be found, and Im just stuck and unsure what I can do to increase coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
const component = mount(<MyComponent/>);
component.find('#dropdown').at(0).simulate('change', {
    target: { value: 'item1', name: 'item1' }
});
```